# Remove Domain Mapping

Tags: domain-mapping, customization

To give you an idea about my experience with Wordpress...its none. I've got a wordpress site from a client of mine to manage. I have years of experience with websites so I'm confident I can do this. Or.. I was. I want to run the site locally via MAMP to make changes and then push them via Git to the remote server. But...the site I got is mapped to the remote domain name. So everytime I want to go to the local domain I'm forwarded to the remote domain.

I can't get in to the admin, I tried replacing all absolute paths in the database (https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB). I checked all files...and now I'm out of ideas. What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Search and replace was a good try - some WP sites also set URLs in the `wp-config.php` file at the root. Check and see if `WP_HOME` or `WP_SITEURL` are set there. https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

Comment: I agree check wp-config, but the URLs you did need to change in the database are 'siteurl' and 'home' in the wp_options table. They're usually the first two rows. You might want to check any .htaccess you've got too in case you've got a rewrite-to-HTTPS rule there that's sending you to the public site there.

Comment: All of the above, not to mention if your install is `multisite` you will want to check the `wp_blogs` table for mappings as well.

Comment: I started fresh and followed all the steps. It first didn't work but after a browser cache empty. It works perfectly!